# Is there a way to hide text using css and clear space?

Tags: css

I'm trying to come up with a solution for this problem.

I have a control where the background is an image.

The text that I would like on the form is included in the bg image, however for the purpose of accessibilty, I'd like to include it in an H3 tag.

The problem I have encountered with the solutions I have is that the space is still allocated and I need it to be supressed. It also needs to be Google friendly too.

Here's 2 solutions I have:

```
text-indent:-999px;

text-indent:100%;  
white-space:nowrap;  
overflow:hidden;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all

```
display: none;
```

But, if you want, there might be other solutions for styling your heading tag

```
/* on its container */
overflow: hidden;

/* on h3 tag */
float: left;
margin-left: -100%;
```

or

```
font-size: 0;
line-height: 0;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
```

You may also need to set/reset few other properties, to clear any other space around your heading, like

```
margin, padding, white-space, text-indent, border, etc.
```

Comment: But, I usually use `display: none;`

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to hide elements is to use one of the following:

`visibility:hidden;` which hides the element but still takes up space.

`display:none;` which hides the element and does not take up space.

I believe the second is what you want in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can give `font-size:0;` to your **h3** tag HEADING will be in your code with your background.
And this will help you in **SEO** also..
**[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/Vz96CodY)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">    
  <h3>heading</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrap {
   height: 230px;
   width:660px;
   background:url("http://www.eldercarefunding.org/Portals/18/Skins/s_eldercare_green/images/header.bgL.png") no-repeat 0 0;

}
#wrap h3 {
  font-size:0;
}
```